# Editing CreatedDate on a publishing page using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, publishing-page

I am trying to move some publishing pages from an old SharePoint server to a new one using powershell. When I try to update the createdDate it says the property is read only. Is there a way to change createdDate and modified date for a publishing page using powershell?

Comment: So basically you are creating new list items, but with the same file? Are you referring to the field "Created"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have minor versioning enabled on the list, you can try to switch it of during the update.

```
$list.EnableMinorVersions = $false
$list.Update()

// Update items
$aListItem["Created"] = yourNewDate
$aListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()

// When done, enable minor versions again
$list.EnableMinorVersions = $true
$list.Update()
```

Comment: I used your code in my powershell but the modified date is exacat the date the powershell created the page. here is my code inside the page layout: <SharePointWebControls:FormField ID="FormField2" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Modified" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try to get list item(page) and update "Created" field:

```
$item["Created"] = Get-Date "5/1/2006 7:00 AM"
$item.Update()
```

Another option might be to create your custom field and copy data to it.

Comment: I used your code but it casts an exception and says something like invalid cast. my date is yyyy-mm-dd.